# Visual Studio Profiler output

Tags: c#, visual-studio, profiling

I wrote a small class that executes `Main()`, which in turn executes `A()`. I expected the `Main()` method to be on its own at the root of the stack call, because it's the topmost function in my application. Everything that's done, should be executed *by* `Main()`. I wrote the following code to test that:

```
namespace ProfilerTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static int _a;

        static void Main()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                A();
            }
        }

        static void A()
        {
            _a += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

The output of the Profiler Call Tree, however, shows that `A()` isn't only executed through `Main()`, it's also executed at the same level as the main function.

[image: Profiler Call Tree output]

What I expected (notice I removed the last line from the call tree):

```
ProfilerTest.exe              10.333
  ProfilerTest.Program.Main   10.333
    ProfilerTest.Program.A    5.897
```

Why is this? Is what I'm expecting incorrect? Or do I misinterpret the profiler results?

Comment: Interesting.  I wonder if this has to do with it being a static method and that both Main() and A() "kinda exist at the same level" and we are seeing the work of incrementing variable a and the call to the static method A() being separated.