# Visual Studio profiler confusing report

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, profiler

My question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29627551/visual-studio-profiler-output) but nobody answered it, so I post again hoping for an answer.

I'm profiling a C++ console app with the visual studio 2013 profiler, CPU sampling. When I look at the call tree I get this:

[image]

This confuses me. Why a mainCRTStartup and __tmainCRTStartup childs? my demo.exe app is just a loop that gets video frames from a file and passes them to a track_background function!

If we look inside the mainCRTStartup and __tmainCRTStartup childs we find:
[image]

and

[image]

so both mainCRTStartup and __tmainCRTStartup end up calling track_background, but why these two functions if I only call track_background from a single point??